# Why can’t a mapped type fully resolve a lookup using a generic, but finite, key?

Tags: typescript

Here’s a reduction of the problem:

```
type Animal = 'dog' | 'cat';

type AnimalSound<T extends Animal> = T extends 'dog'
    ? 'woof'
    : T extends 'cat'
    ? 'meow'
    : never;

const animalSoundMap: {[K in Animal]: AnimalSound<K>} = {
    dog: 'woof',
    cat: 'meow',
};

const lookupSound = <T extends Animal>(animal: T): AnimalSound<T> => {
    const sound = animalSoundMap[animal];
    return sound; 
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4AoB0SWRVNAZQIFc48APABUoEAB7AI-AM5tk6AHxYoI8ZJm5CJBlF1QA-LgDuBAgDMcOvQC4VoiVLyyc1Wld2GcSCASOW9ULZwEABuEABOjAyUBHDSwFAo7OjcfHgAsihgtgDeANoA0lAIcHIcALq28PJcvPwCBQoAvso57lBatjgm5jgANO2uXd6+-QxNUTFxCWimANY8YKn8ysL26k5ligAUSTW2QgCUVcm1acJKmEptAVPxUNJ1eMp7HMsZWXmv6OWMAeEQYA8cKlR5pOhQcZAA)

The `return` line is an error; the error message suggests that the `sound` variable is resolved to `'woof' | 'meow'`, even though it *seems* like TS should be able to type it as `AnimalSound<T>` based on the type of `animalSoundMap`. So why doesn’t the typechecker like it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's an *answer* to the question you've asked, so I'll just post a comment: The simplified case can be addressed by declaring `animalSoundMap` `as const` (`const animalSoundMap = { dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow', } as const;`) and letting TypeScript use inference for all the `AnimalSound` stuff (`const lookupSound = <T extends Animal>(animal: T) => { const sound = animalSoundMap[animal]; return sound; };`), [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WK81Dw). Perhaps that would scale to your real use case, or perhaps not. Hope it helps!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe you can post your solution as an answer. I such cases there are two options: you either pass config object as an extra argument and infer it or make config object fully immutable so TS is able to infer it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make TypeScript happy, I believe you should stick with @T.J. Crowder's solution or with this one:

```js
type Animal = 'dog' | 'cat';

type AnimalSound<T extends Animal> = T extends 'dog'
    ? 'woof'
    : T extends 'cat'
    ? 'meow'
    : never;

const animalSoundMap: { [K in Animal]: AnimalSound<K> } = {
    dog: 'woof',
    cat: 'meow',
};

const lookupSound = <
    AnimalName extends Animal,
    AnimalMap extends { [Name in AnimalName]: AnimalSound<Name> }
>(animalMap: AnimalMap, animal: AnimalName):
    AnimalMap[AnimalName] =>
    animalMap[animal]
```

If you want to infer return type, you should also infer and make a part of function arguments `animalMap`.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4AoB0SWRVNAZQIFc48APABUoEAB7AI-AM5tk6AHxYoI8ZJm5CJBlF1QA-LgDuBAgDMcOvQC4VoiVLyyc1Wld2GcSCASOW9ULZwEABuEABOjAyUBHDSwFAo7OjcfHgAsihgtgDeUADaANJQCHByHAC6tvDyXLz8AoVKAL7KOe5QWrY4JuY4ADQdrt3evgMMzVExcQlopgDWPGCp-MoCHTUcAHIo3vbqTuXogwGb6Jlg%2046yefk7e6VHaPcQVU8rgi8tDAoAFEm1C7VZJoC79RIg4G1F4ASmsGxBF3yZ2eu1eWAUHQBHCR2PQFQYQA)

You don't even need to define explicit return type, TS is able to infer it from function body:

```js
const lookupSound = <T extends Animal>(animal: T)=> {
    const sound = animalSoundMap[animal];

    return sound;
}

const result = lookupSound('cat') // "meow"
```

Conditional types does not work in a way you expect in a place of return type. It may work if you use conditional type in a function overloading:

```js
function lookupSound<T extends Animal>(animal: T): AnimalSound<T>
function lookupSound<T extends Animal>(animal: T) {
    const sound = animalSoundMap[animal];
    return sound;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is caused by `AnimalSound<T>` being a conditional type, and Typescript resolves conditional types later than other types; specifically, when `T extends ...` uses a type parameter, it is not resolved until `T` is bound to a concrete type. So inside the function, where `T` is just a formal type parameter, it can't reason about `AnimalSound<T>` in the way you want.

To avoid this, I recommend making `animalSoundMap`'s type the one you use:

```
type AnimalSoundMap = {[K in Animal]: AnimalSound<K>}

const animalSoundMap: AnimalSoundMap = {
    dog: 'woof',
    cat: 'meow',
};

const lookupSound = <T extends Animal>(animal: T): AnimalSoundMap[T] => {
    return animalSoundMap[animal];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4AoB0SWRVNAZQIFc48APABUoEAB7AI-AM5tk6AHxYoI8ZJm5CJBlF1QA-LgDuBAgDMcOvQC4VoiVLyyc1Wld2GcSCASOW9ULZwEABuEABOjMzg0PDyXLz8ALIoYMoA3gDaANJQCHByHAC6tnEc3HyC2QoAvkyUBHDSwFAo7OgVyaml7QmVKWnY6e5QWrY4JuY4ADQjruPevjMMNVENTS1opgDWPGCdeMrC9upOhYoAFG3xtkIAlD3xBwOZQkVYSsMB4RDAPOEFa7lRJ4F5A9BFRh1IA)

You may find it more convenient to define them the other way round, so that `Animal` and `AnimalSound<T>` and derived from `AnimalSoundMap` rather than vice versa. In this case you get the correct behaviour for `AnimalSound<T>` when `T` is a formal type parameter, and you also can avoid repetition by making `animalSoundMap`'s value the definition of the types (rather than using the types to check that the value is correct).

```
const animalSoundMap = {
    dog: 'woof',
    cat: 'meow',
};

type AnimalSoundMap = typeof animalSoundMap
type Animal = keyof AnimalSoundMap
type AnimalSound<T extends Animal> = AnimalSoundMap[T]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhmAlgWzgGwMogK5gCYCycADjALwwDeAUDHTHiAOYBcMA5AO4ggBm7AGlr1gcKG3bIApiE6DqAXwDc1alACexKTACCSVJhz4ipChq194+9FlyESazdr0p05GAGsp6yy4O3jB3Nna0M7AB4AFRgpAA8oKXwIXVCAPnc-GyN7YgBtSIBdVVBIWDQeD2xiALx3KJj4xLxkzLRUgAoEVzQ2SIBKNlaaqPSydJp6GBLoGAhs9y7-bJNcxfQClUmAJykobC2wWeylGEUVIA)

Comment: I’d like to mark this as correct, because it contains the insight that leads to a solution: “the problem here is caused by AnimalSound<T> being a conditional type, and Typescript resolves conditional types later than other types”. However the specific solution you propose just pushes the problem onto the caller of `lookupSound()`, assuming they still want an `AnimalSound<K>`. A more complete solution is to define AnimalSound in terms of a type that maps animals to sounds (link in second comment).

Comment: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkATAewHMcoAfXAYxWBwG4AoB0SWRVNAZQIFc48AsijBYoAbwZQpUQkQBcuAO4ECAM3qTp1YApxIIBRRoC+jZuGjxk6bnzwAeACpQIAD2AR+AZzbW0APlErDlt+ITAAbUcAXTNKAjgvYCgUdhteMOEFMQiAaSgEOF8OaIVg9Lt7XP9jUQlpGWJdZTUcABpNKW1dfUN2hlMmeMTktBUAax4wULxRJxd3TzwfcoCAClS-BUcASjK0rgyHR0DMQPqtBKSoLyPRTZCj8IiH9FjOqAAnCGAeT6LbnY6FABkA) to demonstrate. Anyway, if you’d like to update your answer along those lines, happy to mark it correct!

Comment: @outoftime I've edited. I originally wrote it the way I did since that's the smaller fix that solves your problem and answers the question as written; the second way won't work if somebody needs a conditional type for some other reason, or if the conditional type comes from third-party code which they can't change. I agree that it's worth adding the second way in case that makes more sense for you or anyone else.